# Copy N first chars from NSString to NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have NSString itemTitle with X length

I want to copy only N (N < X ) to my NSMutable string

What i have tried is :

```
     NSMutableString* title = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:10];//10 =N
     [title appendString:itemTitle];
```

But unfortunately it copies all the NSString as is:(

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Please look at the docs for `NSString`. There are various "substring" related methods.

Comment: Well it is cool when you know where to look.

Comment: How would not know where to look in this case? Your question was about `NSString`. The 1st thing to do is look at the methods and properties of the classes related to your question. That should always be the 1st thing you do. Half the answers I make on this site are begun by first looking at the reference docs. The more you look at them the more you learn about new features.

Comment: Well I didn't even know NSString has a functions :)

Comment: It doesn't have functions, it has methods. I suggest you take some time and find a good tutorial on the Objective-C programming language. It's important to learn the basics of the language before you dig any deeper into iOS development. The time spent doing that now will save you untold amounts of time down the road.

Comment: Ok,cheers!Thanks for comments btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *title = [NSMutableString stringWithString: [itemTitle substringToIndex: MIN(itemTitle.length, 10)]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Capacity of `NSMutableString` is its *initial* capacity, not the final one. When the object needs more space, it allocates more memory, ignoring the capacity that you passed in.

In order to avoid strings that are too long, you could either get a substring of `N` characters before appending, or remove extra characters after the append method has finished:

```
NSMutableString* title = [[itemTitle substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)] mutableCopy];
```

or

```
 NSMutableString* title = [NSMutableString string];//10 =N
 [title appendString:itemTitle];
 [title deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10, title.length)];
```

Note: you need to check that `itemTitle` is indeed longer than ten characters before using either one of these two code snippets.

Comment: Keep in mind that both of these options will crash if `itemTitle` is less than 10 characters in length.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, I added a note explaining that there needs to be a length check before using either of these two options. Thanks!